# XSLT - Create duplicate nodes from an XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a multi level XML, I need to duplicate a set of nodes with a new node using XSLT 1.0 Below is a sample xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Parent>
   <ChildL1 Childtype="A">
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1>
         <ChildL1L2/>
      </ChildL1L1>
   </ChildL1>
   <ChildL1 Childtype="B">
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1/>
   </ChildL1>
</Parent>
```

Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Parent>
   <ChildL1 Childtype="A">
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1>
         <ChildL1L2/>
      </ChildL1L1>
   </ChildL1>
   <ChildL1 Childtype="B">
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1/>
   </ChildL1>
<NewNode>
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1/>
</NewNode>    
</Parent>
```

Here the NewNode has the Children nodes of ChildL1 only when Childtype="B".

Thanks in Advance; Let me know if this question is not clear. It is my first time posting this type of question.

**Editing to show deeper xml nodes:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Parent>
   <ChildL1 Childtype="A">
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1>
         <ChildL1L2>
            <ChildL1L3 index="1"/>
            <ChildL1L3 index="2"/>
            <ChildL1L3 index="3"/>
         </ChildL1L2>
      </ChildL1L1>
   </ChildL1>
   <ChildL1 Childtype="B">
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1/>
   </ChildL1>
</Parent>
```

**desired output(pick Parent/ChildL1/ChildL1L1/ChildL1L2/ChildL1L3 where ChildL1/Childtype='A')**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Parent>
   <ChildL1 Childtype="A">
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1>
         <ChildL1L2>
            <ChildL1L3 index="1"/>
            <ChildL1L3 index="2"/>
            <ChildL1L3 index="3"/>
         </ChildL1L2>
      </ChildL1L1>
   </ChildL1>
   <ChildL1 Childtype="B">
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1/>
   </ChildL1>
<NewNode>
            <ChildL1L3 index="1"/>
            <ChildL1L3 index="2"/>
            <ChildL1L3 index="3"/>
</NewNode>    
</Parent>
```

Comment: Your xml is not valid, and it is making it difficult to know exactly what you want. In the first example, <ChildL1L2> opens, but it doesn't close. Also, you have  <ChildL1 Childtype="B">, but from the corresponding close tag in the indentation, the element name is not matching. Copy and paste it into http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Comment: Sorry, and thanks for pointing out. I closed <ChildL1L2> now. I will try @StuartLC solution

Comment: "*Here the NewNode has the Children nodes of ChildL1 only when Childtype="B".*" That's not what I see. IMHO, your question would be a lot clearer if your nodes had a unique ID - so one could see which `ChildL1L1` is which.

Comment: That's clearer, but what is the **logic** behind the transformation? Do you want to hardcode the `Parent/ChildL1/ChildL1L1/ChildL1L2/ChildL1L3` path into the stylesheet?

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k looks like I tangled the question/answer, initially I had Childtype='A' in mind but posted ='B'. I am editing  the original question for clarity. Thank you

Comment: Yes, for example there can be many children nodes to every node, I need to pick these specific nodes (and their children) to be part of NewNode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is reasonably straightforward with the [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) (and a variant to copy child nodes)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ChildL1[@Childtype='B']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <NewNode>
            <xsl:copy-of select="child::node()"></xsl:copy-of>
        </NewNode>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As per `LeBarton's` comment, you'll want to fix your Xml, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Parent>
   <ChildL1 Childtype="A">
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1>
         <ChildL1L2 />
      </ChildL1L1>
   </ChildL1>
   <ChildL1 Childtype="B">
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1 foo="bar"/>
      <ChildL1L1/>
   </ChildL1>
</Parent>
```

The result is (assuming `ChildL1/@Childtype='B'`s nodes are to be copied)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Parent>
    <ChildL1 Childtype="A">
        <ChildL1L1 />
        <ChildL1L1 />
        <ChildL1L1>
            <ChildL1L2 />
        </ChildL1L1>
    </ChildL1>
    <ChildL1 Childtype="B">
        <ChildL1L1 />
        <ChildL1L1 foo="bar" />
        <ChildL1L1 />
    </ChildL1>
    <NewNode>
        <ChildL1L1 />
        <ChildL1L1 foo="bar" />
        <ChildL1L1 />
    </NewNode>
</Parent>
```

Comment: Hi @StuartLC, thanks for your response! I think I understand the high level direction of your xslt. How would I modify this to pick a node deeper than just 1st level...say 3rd or 4th level.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the exact output you are looking for? e.g. Instead of `child::node()` you can specify an arbitrary xpath to copy to a deeper descendant.

Comment: Hi @StuartLC, I updated the question now. I understood that 'child::node()' is some kind of in-built function so wanted to see how to pick a node which is not immediate child node.

Comment: Your second example seems to conflict with the first - in the first case, it is apparant you want to copy the children of `Childtype="B"` under NewNode, whereas in the second example, you copy the children of `Childtype="A"?

Comment: Hi @StuartLC, I confused everyone, I apologize. Childtype A or B are just my made-up examples to understand the approach to solution. Thank you for your time and solution.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your edited question - this too is fairly straightforward:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Parent">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <NewNode>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ChildL1[@Childtype='A']/ChildL1L1/ChildL1L2/ChildL1L3"/>
        </NewNode>    
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Parent>
   <ChildL1 Childtype="A">
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1>
         <ChildL1L2>
            <ChildL1L3 index="1"/>
            <ChildL1L3 index="2"/>
            <ChildL1L3 index="3"/>
         </ChildL1L2>
      </ChildL1L1>
   </ChildL1>
   <ChildL1 Childtype="B">
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1/>
      <ChildL1L1/>
   </ChildL1>
   <NewNode>
      <ChildL1L3 index="1"/>
      <ChildL1L3 index="2"/>
      <ChildL1L3 index="3"/>
   </NewNode>
</Parent>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will apply this to my data scenario. Thanks again!